# Can't Access The Snapshot.data in Futurebuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

`I Have created this class named DashboardModel with 4 items:`

```
class DashboardModel {
  int status;
  String message;
  List<dynamic> errors;
  Data data;

  DashboardModel({
    this.status,
    this.message,
    this.errors,
    this.data,
  });
}
```

`No problem here.`
**Then I have this function for getting the info from my API as below:**

```
Future<DashboardModel> getDashboard() async {
    var url = "https://SomeAPI.kuttenbugeservice.ru";
    var _pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = _pref.getString('token');
    var header = {'token': token, 'najvaToken': _pref.getString('najvaToken')};
    var response = await http.get(url, headers: header);
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    var model = DashboardModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    return model;
  }
```

Then I want to get the model returned by `getDashboard()` and display it As below:

> FutureBuilder > builder > AnimatedSwitcher > child:

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: _service.getDashboard(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            print('Must Be Ckecked${snapshot.data}');
            return AnimatedSwitcher(
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                child: (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                    ? Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Container(
                          child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                            color: Colors.amber,
                          ),
                        ))
                    : **HomeViewPagerFul(
                   data: snapshot.data,
                 );**
                );
          },
        ),
```

Problem Starts here as the `{snapshot.data}` which holds the `loaded DashboardModel` can't be passed to `HomeViewPagerFul()` as content.

**Below As You can see I have printed the snapshot.data to see what is wrong:**

```
print('Must Be Ckecked${snapshot.data}');
```

but It returns :

```
I/flutter ( 9806): Must Be Ckecked[Instance of 'DashboardModel']
```

=======================================================

So basically the Dashboard model is fine. the getdashboard() function is doing it's job.
FutureBuilder is Showing promise but I can't access the snapshot.

`I can't use snapshot.data.status which I can Access in getDashboard()`

**Simply I face this error:**

```
A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'DashboardModel'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'DashboardModel'.
```

**The HomeViewPagerFul() if needed:**

```
class HomeViewPagerFul extends StatefulWidget {
  final DashboardModel data;

  HomeViewPagerFul({required this.data});

  @override
  _HomeViewPagerFulState createState() => _HomeViewPagerFulState();
}
```

Comment: are you using null-safety ?

Comment: Yes but I don't believe that is the problem. As I said The {snapshot.data} has a value but it's not fit for my 'DashboardModel'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues:

1. You should specify the type to `FutureBuilder`: `FutureBuilder<DashboardModel>`
2. `snapshot` does not have the data while its loading, you should check `snapshot.hasData` and display a loading widget if the data has not yet been fetched

Concretely:

```dart
FutureBuilder<DashboardModel>(
  future: _service.getDashboard(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return LoadingWidget();
    }
    print('Must Be Ckecked${snapshot.data}');
    return AnimatedSwitcher(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      child: (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          ? Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Container(
                child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                ),
              ))
          : HomeViewPagerFul(
              data: snapshot.data!, // Safe since you checked if hasData
            ),
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Lulupointu!! Can't believe it worked! Although I had to add a null-safety-sign(!) in here:   ```HomeViewPagerFul(data: snapshot.data!),``` And do a flutter clean but aside that, ALL IS GOOD:

Comment: Oh yes you are right, I updated my answer. `flutter clean` seems weird but it can't hurt so why not :D